# Disabling Apple mach-o linker errors in xcode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, compiler-errors, xcode4.5, kobold2d

Is it possible to disable xcode from checking for apple mach-o linker errors?

Comment: Yes, by fixing them! A linker error generally isn't something you can ignore. Tell us which error you get, I or someone else might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to make sure you are adding all the necessary frameworks and importing them where ever necessary, And also, check under the compile sources under the build phases that your class files are included there, and Mach-o-linker's would never come in your way.